# Using python to search JSON

Tags: python, json, api

I have done a search of a specific Github API and produced a JSON of the results. It is formatted as follows:

```
[
  {
    "days": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "total": 0,
    "week": 1478995200
  },
  {
    "days": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "total": 3,
    "week": 1479600000
  },
```

etc...

I am trying to use Python to search this dictionary for the week with the highest "total," but I am not exactly sure how to do this. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: have you done any research into how to process json? Have you read the documentation for the json module? That would be the first step: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

Comment: What you have is a list of objects (dictionaries). Iterate the list and find the object whose field `total` is the maximum, this is what you are after

Comment: Though this is not as easy as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
  {
    "days": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "total": 0,
    "week": 1478995200
  },
  {
    "days": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "total": 3,
    "week": 1479600000
  }
]

#  Search for the maximum total
max_total = max([item["total"] for item in data])

## Get the items with this maximum total
max_items = [item for item in data if item["total"]==max_total]

##  Using key argument of max function if you only want one item
max(data, key=lambda item:item['total'])
```